# Grouping on "Single Line of Text" field

Tags: list-view, grouping

I have 40000 items in a document library. The threshold is set to 2,000 items at CA.

All documents can render all the items.

But if I add grouping on a column "Contract Number" (which is a combination of letters and numbers) then the view fails and gives following error. The reason for grouping is there are 100s of contract that has the same Contract Number.

What are my options in order to get grouping on columns like these.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80030102 (STG_E_REVERTED)) 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80030102 (STG_E_REVERTED))

Source Error:
```

Comment: Did u tried adding a limit to the view using Item Limit and see if that removes the issue? ALso, did u customized the View or use a SPD designed View?

Comment: Did you try indexing the column?
Are you using any custom code on the page that might dispose of object you shouldn't?

Comment: view limit is 30 per page. The column is indexed. Have not tried to customize using SPD. No other customization on that page that should dispose the web or current context .

Answer (score -1):

the below link may solve your problem..
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/9c515220-b2fd-4e35-a194-4f04c4be8371/option-to-group-by-content-type-is-missing-from-view-settings

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.